# Session is empty when link is opened from another tab with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

the title may not be 100% clear but I have an issue to which I cannot find a solution... Let me (try to) explain :
I have a Laravel application (v5.5) and when I sign in, everything works fine. I can open a new tab, and my session is found so I do not need to sign in again, which is perfectly normal. 
Except (!!!) when I click on a link (i.e from an email) from another tab : when I do this, I need to sign in.

It seems that the session data is completely empty and cannot be retrieved through the cookie. But if I open a new tab and try accessing the url by doing a simple copy/paste in the browser, I'm successfully logged in.

Moreover, after asking for my login/password after clicking the link from the other tab, the application does not redirect me to the queried url as it's supposed to, but rather redirect me to the home page.

Has anyone faced this issue? And maybe successfully solved it?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure about your URL to your application? it must be the same from email too. if you have e.g. localhost/mysite and mysite.localhost its not the same.

Comment: @db1975, the url is the exact same. I do a right click > copy address link and paste it directly into my browser, and this works fine that way...

Comment: is the opened Browser the same Browser?

Comment: the exact same. I've tried on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevent but I've recently upgraded from 5.4 to 5.5. And I think (it's a project I've taken over) it worked fine before the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out what was wrong: I had configured the "same_site" option to "strict" instead of "lax"... It works fine now !